# How to unlink a Facebook user in Cloud Code on Parse Server?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

On Parse iOS SDK the method `PFFacebookUtils.unlinkUserInBackground(_:)` can be used to unlink a Facebook user from the Parse user record.

Unlinking basically deleted the field `authData` value from the user record. However, deleting the value of field `authData` directly is not allowed since it is a Parse Server managed field.

How can a user be unlinked in Cloud Code?

Answer (score 0):

The `authData` field can actually be modified via REST.

So a workaround to delete it in CloudCode is this:

```
// Unlink facebook account from user
await Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "PUT",
    url: myServerUrl + "/users/" + user.id,
    headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': myApplicationId,
        'X-Parse-Master-Key': myMasterKey,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        "authData": {
            "facebook": null
        }
    }
});
```